Issue with SPA Integration: Next.js and ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm trying to integrate a Next.js (v14) frontend with an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API backend. My API does not work when I use app.UseSpa.
However, when I comment out app.UseSpa you can see before app.Run(), the API works fine.
I am new to Nextjs and ASP.NET Core Web API, also tell me what are and why these are used SPA, proxies.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalhost3000",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/.next";
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowLocalhost3000");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp");

   if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:3000");
    }
});

app.Run();


Test Result



My Sample Project

Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Next_API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/.next";
            });
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/c npm run dev", 
                    WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp"),
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                app.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();

                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

                app.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                });
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}


Thank you @Jason for your answer it is really helpful but the directory structure seems different let me how you installed Nextjs, I first made a .Net Core web Api template then installed Nextjs using npm install create-next-app@latest

@CodeRed Sure, please let me know if you need further help.

hey! @JasonPan my controller API is still not working giving Status code 404 I am attaching the images with the question

Hi @CodeRed Please share me your Test comtroller code, the 404 means the url is wrong.

I have attached the Test Controller image

Hi @CodeRed After investigating the issue, I found this description(https://github.com/davidnx/NextjsStaticHosting-AspNetCore?tab=readme-ov-file#why-asp-net-core).

@CodeRed And we know there is no working sample for [nextjs with asp.net core api], so I think it's impossible to implement this directly, we have to use this package.

oh thanks, @JasonPan for clearing things up, Anyway, I think I should go for Reactjs now
